# Extract month in R

Tags: r, date

I have a sequence of dates in R with 2 months.

Example:

> 2020-01-28 /
>   2020-01-29 /
>   2020-01-30 /
>   2020-01-31 /
>   2020-02-01 /
>   2020-02-02

I need to extract the dates with the first month, in that case, January. But, I'm not able to do this.

I already tried to use `subset`, but didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your example is unclear. Can you share an R object via `dput()` (paste it in as a code)?

Comment: Is this a string? a list? a matrix? It is a good practice to provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It improves your chance to get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get a vector with the month value. Here is an example, assuming that your data are in a vector like I did :

```
date = c("2020-01-28","2020-01-29","2020-01-30","2020-01-31","2020-02-01","2020-02-02")
library(lubridate)
month(date) # get the month value only
# [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2
january <- date[month(date)==1] # extract only the date which are in the 1st month
january
# [1] "2020-01-28" "2020-01-29" "2020-01-30" "2020-01-31"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
r <- subset(v,format(as.Date(v),"%b") == "Jan")
```

**DATA**

```
v <- c("2020-01-28", "2020-01-29", "2020-01-30", "2020-01-31", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-02")
```

Comment: I would rather prefer `subset(v,format(as.Date(v),"%m") == "01")`